# Click button on zk Modal with Watir

Tags: watir, zk

I have a login page, so, when a fill credentials and that credentials aren´t correct,
my page open a modal zk window.
I want to click a button in that window. how can I do that?
I use `browser.window(:title=>'Leão').use` to select modal. but watir doen´t recognize ã.
I put `#encoding:utf:8` on top of file but i still have error

Comment: question is not clear .what do you mean by i want to click a bottom in that window? what do you want to ask here?

Comment: sorry, I want to say that I want to click button in that window

Comment: Is it ZK Framework related question if Yes in modal Window its simple to add button by using this tag <button lable="myButton"/> but it look like different.

Comment: @subodhjoshi he's using [Watir](http://watir.com/) to test his ZK application

Comment: yes, I´m using watir to test my zk application. I got it `browser.window(:title=>//).use do`, but as you can see I didn´t put the title of window, because my windows title have special caracters like ã or ç. and when I execute ruby program.rb on cmd, it doesn´t recognize the title.

Comment: Sorry i was not aware about it